# haskell replicate function "+----+--+"

Tags: haskell

```
print_line :: [Int] -> String
print_line numbers = case numbers of
    []      ->  []
    n:ns    -> '+' :replicate n '-' ++ print_line ns
```

I want when you give the Print_line function a list of Int for example [8,2] it returns
    "+--------+--+"
the function at the moment will return "+--------+--" how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `+` for the `[]` case:

```
print_line :: [Int] -> String
print_line numbers = case numbers of
    []      ->  "+"
    n:ns    -> '+' :replicate n '-' ++ print_line ns
```

I didn't test it though and it has been a while since I programmed in Haskell the last time.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a small helper function writing the whole thing pointfree you get

```
import Data.List

printLine :: [Int] -> String
printLine = between '+' . intercalate "+" . map (`replicate` '-')
  where between c str =  c:(str ++[c])
```

### Edit

If I would use these a lot I would even go further and make extra functions like

```
fillWith c = map (`replicate` c)
sepBy = intercalate
between c str = c:(str++[c])
```

so I could write `printLine = between '+' . sepBy '+' . fillWith '-'` which reads much alike the (Atto/Mega/Parsec-) parser that I would write to parse a String like this, it also has the flexibility of changing the whole thing easily if my end result string should look like `|----+-----------+-----|`, or `|=========|========|========|`.

Comment: You might also like the `foldr` version, 
`printLine = foldr (fmap ('+':) . (++) . flip replicate '-') "+"`  
... or of course if you like parentheses `fmap ('+' :)` expands in this case to `(('+' :) .)` and as you've written one can write `flip replicate '-'` with backticks at the cost of even more parens.

Comment: @CRDrost I find the original simple and instantly understandable; this answer's version is nice but only after some concentration; and yours requires squinting for quite some time before I can decipher it (and even then I'm not sure I got it right).

Comment: @CRDrost If I had performance issues with my function - yours is one that I would keep in mind for a benchmark and replacing the one I did, if necessary, though I would write a comment why this was done with `foldr` and a short explanation and a quickcheck testcase with the original. I wrote this answer with "readability" in mind less with a performance centric view.

Comment: @DanielWagner That is ever the problem with `foldr`, it requires a sort of magical thinking. If I were doing it more readable-like I suppose the complicated function in the middle can be rendered `segmentFromInt n = ('+' :) . (replicate n '-' ++)` with `segmentFromInt :: Int -> String -> String`, and then the whole thing is `foldr segmentFromInt "+" nums`. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple hack using `Data.List`

```
import Data.List

print_line x=intercalate "+" . map (flip replicate '-') $ [0]++x++[0]
```

Comment: `concat (replicate n "-")` might be better written as `replicate n '-'`, and `concat (intersperse "+" xs)` is `intercalate "+" xs`. So a bikeshed version might be ```print_line ns = intercalate "+" ([""] ++ map (`replicate` '-') ns ++ [""])```.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!. Really shortened everything.